# How to create Magento Config Yesno in custom phtml template in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create magento default Yesno option in custom phtml template.
This can be created in system.xml by using this code.

```
<field id="testID" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
       <label>Custom Select Option</label>
       <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
```

But how this can be created in my custom phtml template.

Comment: you can use magento select class from admin

Comment: Frontend or Backend ?

Comment: i post my answer which works for me

Answer (score 1):

> You can use **`select class`** from admin

check and try this below code in your **`custom phtml`**:

```
<select name="yesno" class="select admin__control-select">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Save config not saving this option

Comment: are you implementing it on a system.xml config file?

Comment: a block is called from system.xml and this block call that phtml file. If another module is enabled than this select option should display.

Comment: I see, it is a little bit complicated. can you add your system config code in your post.

Comment: i done this by using save config hook. Thanks for your time

Comment: great! post your solution and  that might be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this maybe this will help others.

My system.xml

```
<field id="testID" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Custom Select Option</label>
   <source_model>Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Custom</source_model>
</field><br>
```

My Block file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class RADforLiftgate extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
const TEMPLATE = 'system/config/custom.phtml';

protected $_moduleManager;
public $enable = 'no';

/**
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_scopeConfig     = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_moduleManager   = $moduleManager;
    $this->checkOtherModule();
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
        $this->setTemplate(static::TEMPLATE);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * checkOtherModule
 */
protected function checkOtherModule() 
{
    if($this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('OtherVendor_OtherModule')){
        $this->enable = 'yes';
    }
}
/**
 * Retrieve element HTML markup.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
{
    $this->setNamePrefix($element->getName())
        ->setHtmlId($element->getHtmlId());

    return $this->_toHtml();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param  $name 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIsChecked()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("vendor/module/custom", \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
}<br>
```

My phtml file

```
<?php
if($this->enable == 'yes'){ ?>
    <select name="custom" class=" select admin__control-select" 
            data-ui-id="select-groups-third-fields-custom-value">
        <option value="no" <?php echo ($this->getIsChecked() == 'no')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>No</option>
        <option value="yes" <?php echo ($this->getIsChecked() == 'yes')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Yes</option>
    </select>

<?php } else { ?>      
    <div class="rad">
        <p>
            Click <a href="#">here</a> to read paragraph.            
        </p>
    </div>
```

Now to save this select value on Save Config button. Create a file di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" />
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="admin_system_config_save_fedexltl_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\SaveConfig" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
```

Now final step i create a Model file.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
class SaveConfig{
/**
 *  @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface
 */
protected $_configWriter;
protected $_scopeConfig;

/**
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
 * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_configWriter = $configWriter;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject
 * @param \Closure $proceed
 * @return type
 */
public function aroundSave(
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
) {
    $postData = $this->request->getPostValue();

    if(isset($postData['config_state']['group_section'])){
        $isActive = (isset($postData['groups']['section']['fields']['custom'])
                && $postData['groups']['section']['fields']['custom'] == 'yes') ? 'yes' : 'no';
        $this->_configWriter->save('Vendor/Module/custom',  $isActive, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
    }

    return $proceed();
}
}
```